# Can SSO be used to create a dataflow that will reside in the PBI service?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our client would like us to use dataflows for data reuse and other reasons. We will be connecting to a Snowflake database from PBI service. However, they also want to be able to use SSO (Single Sign-On). So, when a user creates a dataset referencing a dataflow, they want the credentials from the currently logged in user to be picked up via SSO and passed along to Snowflake when the dataflow retrieves data from Snowflake. I don't think this can be done but I wanted to verify.

BTW, I know that SSO can be used with PBI Desktop. Just curious if dataflows can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems is possible to use DataFlows with SSO for Snowflake. I am coming to this conclusion from the following reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/snowflake
which includes DataFlows under Summary - Products.